# Hosting Videos Stored in Google Drive created by Google Meet

Tags: html5-video, mp4, google-sites, google-meet

We use Google Meets a lot to record our meetings. I move the video files to a specific folder and then use GAS to deliver a JSON object of the file information in that folder to a webpage in Google Sites so that I can create a select menu that changes the src attribute of a  tag. The video tag exists in a iframe - this is how Google Sites allows you to embed your own JS. The whole process works and I am using it successfully with other file formats like MP3 on other projects, but those videos recorded by Google Meet cause CORS errors and "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found" errors.

If I download the video and run it through a video editor to convert it to some other version of MP4 and then upload the video back to the folder, they work. But that defeats the purpose and creates more work.

I think this has something to do with how the video is saved/encoded within the Google habitat. Why would one type of MP4 cause the errors but another type would not.

Answer (score 0):

I knew as soon as I asked the question I would figure it out. The trick was to not use the  tag and instead use an iframe with the src set as the video file in the format:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/file_ID/preview

I'm still not sure why the video tag doesn't work with Google's version of MP4 from a Google Meet. But at least this is a workaround.